# I am trying to dynamically print out from a text field I have the list that says what to do and what to say

Tags: javascript

I have successfully done it with one thing going on, but I have two things going on I want to dynamically print that out from the values of two different tables. here is my code: when a button is clicked it goes to another page that prints out what the user filled into the text field. here is how I am doing it:

```
    function print_list(item_names,number_of_items) {
      var theText="<ol>";
      for(var i=1; i<=number_of_items;i++){
        if($("#" + item_names + "_" + i).val()!=''){
        theText+="<li>"
        theText+=$("#" + item_names + "_" + i).val();   
        theText+="</li>";

        }

    }
    theText +="</ol>";
    $("#print_content_area").html(theText);
    Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('printArea_1'), function(elem){
        $(".printing_list").printElement( elem );
    });
}
```

I need to seperate two different fields here is the table for that

```
<div id="blue_small_header_text" align="left" style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What to 

   say and do <div id="list_buttons"><a class="print_list"    
     onclick="print_list2('activities_say',3);"></a><a class="list_help" 
      onclick="openDialog('list_help');"></a></div></div>
        <div id="list_question_btn"></div></div>
           <div id="activity_area_content" style="padding:5px">
            <table  width="100%" style="line-height:0px">
         <tr>
              <td><p style="width:50px;">To say</p></td>
    <td><input class="printArea_1 activities_say1_box" name="activities_say_1"     
         id="activities_say_1"  type="text" placeholder="Type or click the list  
           button &gt;" style="width:340px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="say_1"  class="list_btn list_say" value="List                  &gt;"          /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-size:9px;">&nbsp;To do</td>
    <td align="center"><input class="printArea_1 activities_do_box" name="activities_do_1" id="activities_do_1" type="text" placeholder="Type or click the list button &gt;" style="width:340px;" /></td>
    <td><input  type="button" id="do_1" class="list_btn list_do" value="List &gt;" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><p style="width:50px;">To say</p></td>
    <td><input class="printArea_1 activities_say1_box" name="activities_say_2" id="activities_say_2" type="text" placeholder="Type or click the list button &gt;" style="width:340px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="say_2"  class="list_btn list_say" value="List &gt;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:9px;">&nbsp;To do</td>
    <td align="center"><input class="printArea_1 activities_do_box" name="activities_do_2" id="activities_do_2" type="text" placeholder="Type or click the list button &gt;" style="width:340px;" /></td>
    <td><input  type="button" id="do_2"  class="list_btn list_do" value="List &gt;" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><p style="width:50px;">To say</p></td>
    <td><input class="printArea_1 activities_say1_box" name="activities_say_3" id="activities_say_3" type="text" placeholder="Type or click the list button &gt;" style="width:340px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="say_3"  class="list_btn list_say" value="List &gt;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td style="font-size:9px;">&nbsp;To do</td>
    <td  align="center"><input class="printArea_1 activities_do_box" name="activities_do_3" id="activities_do_3" type="text" placeholder="Type or click the list button &gt;" style="width:340px;" /></td>
    <td><input  type="button" id="do_3"  class="list_btn list_do" value="List &gt;" /></td>
</tr>
```

here is the page that is being printed out.

```
    <div class="printing_list" id="printList2" >
      <img id="print_logo" src="/images/print_header_med.png">
    <div align="left" id="printHead_text"></div>
      <br />
    <div align="left" class="listPrint_info" style="width:700px;"></div>
    <br />
        <table  width="100%" style="line-height:20px; margin-left:10px;" >
      <tr id="Say_list">
         <td id="print_content_area2"></td>
</td>
</tr>
            </table>
            <table  width="100%" style="line-height:20px; margin-left:10px;" >
      <tr id="Say_do_list">
         <td id="print_content_area2"></td>
    </td>
    </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't any java here, right? (or mysql)

Comment: I'm editing it to remove the java tag.

Comment: Please format/indent your code correctly